# Convert an Oracle Spatial LineString into a Leaflet GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, oracle, leaflet, oracle-spatial

I am currently trying to convert a LineString from Oracle Spatial into a Leaflet GeoJSON so that I can read from database and add to the map.  I am currently using a library called Terraformer. This is the attached code:

```
var geojson = Terraformer.WKT.parse('LINESTRING (-77.8388214111328 40.6962578192132, -77.9081726074219 40.6655354110279, -78.0084228515625 40.6738683108532)');

map.addLayer(geojson);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create an instance of [`L.GeoJson`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#geojson). A Leaflet map handles instances of `L.Layer`, not arbitrary data.

```
var geojsonFeature = Terraformer.WKT.parse('LINESTRING (....)');

var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(geojsonFeature);

map.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
```

Do read the [Leaflet GeoJSON tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/) also.

Comment: I figured it out I had the wrong instance of leaflet installed into my map.  I used leaflet.omnivore to solve the issue